# What is the purpose of heelpieces?

Tags: orthopedics, clothes, evolution, orthotics, heel

Why do you need the heelpieces? Why did millions years of evoultion develop so short human heel that we need to extend it with the artificial one?

[image]

What are the health implications of having shoes with or without the heelpieces?

Should I stay barefooted or use shoes with heels at home?